# Check if js.Value exists

Tags: go, webassembly

In the JavaScript code, I've:

```
function readAll() {
    var objectStore = db.transaction("employee").objectStore("employee");
    
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
       var cursor = event.target.result;
       
       if (cursor) {
          alert("Name for id " + cursor.key + ", Value: " + cursor.value);
          cursor.continue();
       } else {
          alert("No more entries!");
       }
    };
 }
```

In my equivalent GO code, I wrote:

```golang
    var ReadAll js.Func
    ReadAll = js.FuncOf(func(this js.Value, args []js.Value) interface{} {
        defer ReadAll.Release()
        cursor := this.Get("result")

        if cursor {
                _ = cursor.Get("key")
                value := cursor.Get("value")
                Window.Call("alert", value)
                cursor.Call("continue")

            } else {
                Window.Call("alert", "No more records")
            } 
        return nil
    })

    db.ObjectStore.Call("openCursor").Set("onsuccess", ReadAll)
```

But while compiling, I got:

```sh
non-bool cursor (type js.Value) used as if condition
```

Ho can I check if the related `js.value` exists or no?

Comment: `this.Get("result")` will return a `js.Value`. You can check if it is a boolean, and get the boolean value. Your Go code does not look like the JS code though.

Comment: should this have the `webassembly` tag?  I don't see a Go-specific WASM tag

Comment: @BurakSerdar returned `js.Value` is not a bool, it is an object of (key, Value), moreover I changed the code line, hope now it is clear.

Comment: @DanielFarrell I could not understand your point, however I updated my code above.

Comment: If you want to see whether the result of `Get` is a valid value, check `cursor.Truthy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript `if(cursor)` is checking if the value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Your code `this.Get` result in a `js.Value`. It's not boolean, and you can't use it in a Go `if` clause.

The syscall/js package has `Truthy()` that you can use to mimick javascript truthy check.

https://pkg.go.dev/syscall/js#Value.Truthy

```
if cursor.Truthy() {
  ...
}
```

And to check if a value is falsey, you negate the result:

```
if !cursor.Truthy() {
  ...
}
```